# How to write Hierarchical query in PYTHON

Tags: python, pandas

The given input is like:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID NAME     MANAGER_ID
   101         A       10
   102         B       11
   10          C       1
   11          D       1
   1           E       null


Employee     Cycle      LEVEL Path
   101         A         101/10/1
   102         B         102/11/1
   10          C         10/1
   11          D         11/1
   1           E         1
```

It will be great if one can solve it using python "pandas" library. I am not sure if it can be achieved using pandas or not. Other solutions are also welcomed.

Comment: Where is your try?

Comment: I don't see any apparent relationship between your input and the desired output.

Comment: In Oracle it can be done by using "CONNECT BY" operator. I need to achieve the same in python. I need to tell an employees manager, his manager and so on.... separated by "/" in front of all employees.

Comment: why dont use a loop in python to fill a column with the needed data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`dictionary`** with **`EMPLOYEE_ID`** and **`MANAGER_ID`**:

```
dct = dict(zip(df.EMPLOYEE_ID.values, df.MANAGER_ID.values))
```

**`function`** to create hierarchy string

```
def heirarchy(id):
  boss = str(id) + '/'
  while dct[id] != 'null':
    boss += dct[id] + '/'
    id = int(dct[id])
  return boss[:-1]
```

**`apply`**

```
df['LEVEL'] = df.EMPLOYEE_ID.apply(heirarchy)

# Result

   EMPLOYEE_ID NAME MANAGER_ID     LEVEL
0          101    A         10  101/10/1
1          102    B         11  102/11/1
2           10    C          1      10/1
3           11    D          1      11/1
4            1    E       null         1
```

Comment: what if employee 101 reports to 10 and 10 reports 101, or employee 10 reports to 10 itself. then it will be in a infinite loop. How do you can overcome that.

Comment: I made some change for employee id in string. 
And apply to dataframe is also changed,

``` python
def hierarchy(id):
        boss = str(id) + '/'
        while dct.get(id, '') != "" and dct[id] != id:        # no more manager or self, what if endless looping??
            boss += dct[id] + '/'
            id = dct.get(id, '')    #dct[id]
        return boss[:-1]
    
    df['path'] = df.apply(lambda row : hierarchy(row['EMPLOYEE_ID']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary mapping children to parents.

Then use `pd.Series.apply` to construct your path string via a `while` loop.

Note I assume `null` actually means `NaN`, which makes more sense for a numeric column.

```
child_parent_dict = df.set_index('EMPLOYEE_ID')['MANAGER_ID'].to_dict()

def get_all_parents(child):
    """Get all parents from hierarchy structure"""
    while child == child:
        child = child_parent_dict[child]
        if child == child:
            yield int(child)

def get_path(x):
    """Calculate path and construct string"""
    return '/'.join(list(map(str, [x]+list(get_all_parents(x)))))

df['Path'] = df['EMPLOYEE_ID'].apply(get_path)

print(df)

#    EMPLOYEE_ID NAME  MANAGER_ID      Path
# 0          101    A          10  101/10/1
# 1          102    B          11  102/11/1
# 2           10    C           1      10/1
# 3           11    D           1      11/1
# 4            1    E         NaN         1
```

Comment: what if employee 101 reports to 10 and 10 reports 101, or employee 10 reports to 10 itself. then it will be in a infinite loop.
How do you can overcome that.

Comment: @Bunny, That's another issue: fix your input data. What you have is a problem with the input data, not with the logic I've described.

Comment: @jpp I get `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'` due to the employee without a Manager ID. Taking that top employee out results in `KeyError: '500'` Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I find the method/approach used by user3483203 pretty neat and to the point; the code is simple to follow. The only thing that I'd add is instead of the function returning a '/' delimited string, I'd output a native python structure like a list. Something like this:

```
def get_managerial_hierarchy(employee_id, manager_list=None):
if manager_list == None:
    manager_list = []
manager_list.append(employee_id)
employee_id = parent_child[employee_id]
if employee_id != '':
    get_managerial_hierarchy(employee_id, manager_list)
return manager_list
```

The output will look like this:

```
['101', '10', '1']
['102', '11', '1']
['10', '1']
['11', '1']
['1']
```

You can always wrap/change the list, if necessary, to comply with your desired output. However, now you can now just as easily quantify the distance/level of managerial hierarchy (how many layers apart is the CEO from the lowest staff) by using the len() function. By the way, I used a recursive approach. To scale it out, I'd stick to an iterative solution