# Get all managers of a employee using Python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

This is an extended question to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50428119/how-to-write-hierarchical-query-in-python)

I did used the same DataFrame,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
data = {'EMPLOYEE_ID':[101,102,10,11,1],
        'NAME':['A','B','C','D','E'],
        'MANAGER_ID':[10,11,101,1,None]},
         columns=['EMPLOYEE_ID','NAME','MANAGER_ID'])
df = df.replace('', np.nan)
```

and by referring to @jpp answer, i am getting the desired output.

```
child_parent_dict = df.set_index('EMPLOYEE_ID')['MANAGER_ID'].to_dict()

def get_all_parents(child):
"""Get all parents from hierarchy structure"""
while child == child:
    child = child_parent_dict[child]
    if child == child:
        yield int(child)

def get_path(x):
"""Calculate path and construct string"""
return '/'.join(list(map(str, [x]+list(get_all_parents(x)))))

df['Path'] = df['EMPLOYEE_ID'].apply(get_path)
```

But, then i came across few corner cases.

The referred answer gets failed when

- '101' Emp reports to '10' Manager, and '10' Emp reports to '101'
- when EmpID 102 reports to 11, but 11 EmpID reports to himself.

The DataFrame looks like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
data = {'EMPLOYEE_ID':[101,102,10,11,1],
        'NAME':['A','B','C','D','E'],
        'MANAGER_ID':[10,11,101,11,None]},
columns=['EMPLOYEE_ID','NAME','MANAGER_ID'])
```

Yes, It looks like the data issue, but after all the data is generated by manually or by machines.
So there might be chances of getting data generated as above mentioned.
It is our job to make our script run for these corner cases also.

To solve this, there are two possibilities,

- Exclude the record of that Employee
- Just get the EmployeeID but his Managers

i did tried to exclude employee record by changing in get employees function, but i couldn't make it completely.

```
EmpList = []
def get_all_parents(child):
"""Get all parents from hierarchy structure"""
while child == child:
    print(child_parent_dict[child])
    child = child_parent_dict[child]
    print(child)
    if (child == child and child != 'None'):
        EmpList.append(child)
        print(EmpList)
        yield str(child)
        print(child)
        for i in range(len(EmpList)):
            if len(EmpList) >=3 and (EmpList[0] == EmpList[2]):
                break
    else:
        EmpList.clear()

def get_path(x):
"""Calculate path and construct string"""
print('|'.join(list(map(str, [x]+list(get_all_parents(x))))))
return '|'.join(list(map(str, [x]+list(get_all_parents(x)))))
```

Any thoughts or suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Bunny.

Comment: You will need to implement your own check to avoid loops and self references. I would suggest using `networkx` since this appears to be more suited to graphing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @coldspeed.i think networkx is more of visualisation perspective, but i prefer to create a column as path in dataframe. any help.